# How can I trim Schema/Database Name in MySQL

Tags: mysql

An Application I am using is passing schema name as a string literal and it is getting single quoted and generating MySQL Syntax error:
`'somedatabasename'`

I want to trim the single quotes and use the schema name to form my query.
`SELECT field FROM somedatabasename.sometable`

I can only use a single Query and cannot use Stored Procedure (I know using stored functions I can manipulate the strings.)

Is there a way in MySQL where I can Use `TRIM` or `REPLACE` with the `FROM` keyword.

Comment: No you can't do that , but why aren't you building the whole query?

Comment: The query will run in a BI Application. What do you mean by building the whole query ?

Comment: What is there between the spot where that piece of code you don't control generates a string with the table name and the spot where the query is submitted to MySQL server? This question is tagged only as MySQL. Are you looking for a server feature to rewrite queries or alias objects?

Comment: It's a BI Application  with MySQL Query Editor. This application sends in the `SchemaName` as a Parameter which then I need to use in my Query. If there is a solution that works in MySQL server it will work in this application as well, hence I only Tagged MYSQL.

Comment: And it's Schema Name I am looking to TRIM/ FIX not the Table Name

Comment: I presume the only way to rewrite a query in MySQL server is to re-compile the program's C source code to change its SQL parser or (maybe) write a custom plugin to do that. You could also create some proxy program to rewrite queries on the fly. All these are utterly costly and complicated workarounds.